# How to get status of a layer in geoserver using gsconfig?

Tags: python, geoserver

I am getting all published layers from geoserver using gsconfig using following code:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog  
cat=Catalog("http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/rest")  
myResource = cat.get_resources(store='storeName', workspace='workspaceName')  
layers = cat.get_layers(myResource).
```

Now I want to get all layers which are not published stored (yet to be published) or status of a layer which means published or yet to be published . How can I?

Comment: [Answer available here with geoserver rest][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110287/how-to-get-layer-list-of-layers-that-are-published/111430#comment157835_111430

Comment: I think this can't be accomplished using gsconfig. You need to use REST. Also checkout http://spatialmounty.blogspot.de/2012/12/geoserver-batch-create-layers-from.html for some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
layer = cat.get_layer("yourlayer")
if layer.enabled:
   print "Layer is published"
else:
   print "Layer is not published"
```

Layers provide these settings:

**enabled** is a Boolean flag which may be set to False to stop serving a layer without deleting it. If this is set to True then the layer will be served.

Refer to [this webpage](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/python_gsconfig.html).

Comment: I know this enabling part, i already referred the same web page.I want to know the status  of all layers in a store weather they are published or yet to be published(Action based)..

Comment: You make no reference to the web page in your post, nor do you state you are aware of the enabled attribute.  You simply posted code and asked for help.  My answer ACTUALLY answers part of your question.  If not, then you need to rephrase it and be more clear on what you want.