# How to get layer list of layers that are published?

Tags: python, geoserver

I'm stuck.

I've been using geoserver with python extension gsconfig library for a while now. Almost everything works as it should be. While there are little things like publish raster images are problematic, there is still workaround that isn't written into the catalog.py class.

But there is this where I have no idea how to get around. 
How do you get a list of layer resource objects that unpublished? catalog.py provides get_layers and get_resources that return layers that are published but not the unpublished layers in a datastore.

I could list all the layers (publish and unpublished) in a datastore through geoserver interface but wms/wfs/wcs and even rest does not

The wms/wfs/wcs services can return layer information in xml but still no layers that are unpublished. I could understand why that is in this case since it is publish facing but I don't know why REST services have this problem as well.

I have searched a lot of forum with no luck.

Did anyone manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Same question received an answer from geoserver-users mailing list
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/43129/focus=43205

The advice was to search for available featuretypes with REST as in the example

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XGET -H "Accept: text/xml" http://
localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/mydatastore/featuretypes?list
=available
```

The parameter values are documented in

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html