# Getting GeoServer full datastore layer list by REST

Tags: geoserver, rest, geoserver-rest-api

I have installed GeoServer 2.6.1 with an Oracle datastore which has some of the tables of the database published - the others will be published in the near future.

The [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html) says that It is possible to access to the published layers of the datastore by REST GeoServer service like following:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/[WORKSPACE]/datastores/[DATASTORE].html`

As far as I know, this REST method only lists all layers of the datastore which are published. I would like to know if could be possible to get all layers (published and non published yet) from a specific Geoserver's datastore.

Comment: I think there is an answer to a similar question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110287/how-to-get-layer-list-of-layers-that-are-published).

Comment: It is not the same question. That answer does tell how to get a list of already published layers but this question is about full list of layers including those which are not yet published.

Comment: I think it is duplicate, since the link does talk about which parameter is required for available, ans already configured sources.

Comment: Thank you! I have read all the answers releated with the question that @MickyInTheSky indicated me. It would be quite useful for what I need to do :)